# How to change Custom EndpointAddress for AppInsight

Tags: azure-application-insights

I wanted to send the AppInsight data to a custom web service (which I have created on WebAPI C#.NET). For this I have changed the ApplicationInsight.config file as mentioned below,

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <EndpointAddress>http://MyCustomWebServiceHostedInServer</EndpointAddress>
    <MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity>5</MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity>
</TelemetryChannel>
```

After changing the EndpointAddress in the config file, the AppInsight data is not passed to the web service specified in the endpointaddress.

If anyone has faced the same issue, kindly let me know on the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using .net core application? If yes, ai.config file is not the correct way to modify endpoint. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration#redirect-traffic-to-the-different-endpoint

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am using a web application and the Application Insight has been configured via "App Insight Status Monitor". Once the ai.config file is added by the Status Monitor, I have modified the file for adding the endpoint address as above.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstand you.

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/troubleshoot-faq#proxy), you can add `v2/track` to your custom endpoint, like below:

```
<TelemetryChannel>         
     <EndpointAddress>http://MyCustomWebServiceHostedInServer/v2/track</EndpointAddress>
</TelemetryChannel>
```

Comment: Hi, After changing the EndPointAddress as mentioned by you, it's not working.